# Remove duplicate values in each column in every row pandas python

Tags: python, pandas

I have 4 columns ( Name, Area, State, Email). In column Email has duplicate email after i group by and join the value. The output turns out to be:

```
Area    Group   Shift         Email
KM      MFG     A1,A2,A3      a@gmail.com,a@gmail.com,b@gmail.com
RIM     TEST    A1,B1         c@gmail.com,b@gmail.com,c@gmail.com
PNG    FINISH   C1,C2,C3      a@gmail.com,c@gmail.com,a@gmail.com
KL     Manager  NORMAL,B1,B1  b@gmail.com,a@gmail.com,c@gmail.com,a@gmail.com
```

I need to remove the duplicate email in column 'Email'. Anyone can help me?

Comment: Please show us your grouping code so we can tell you what to change to remove duplicates.

Comment: df = df.groupby(['Area','Group])['Email'].apply(','.join).reset_index()

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you need this:

```
df['Email'] = df['Email'].str.split(',').apply(lambda x: ','.join(set(x)))
```

Output:

```
  Area    Group         Shift                                Email
0   KM      MFG      A1,A2,A3              a@gmail.com,b@gmail.com
1  RIM     TEST         A1,B1              c@gmail.com,b@gmail.com
2  PNG   FINISH      C1,C2,C3              a@gmail.com,c@gmail.com
3   KL  Manager  NORMAL,B1,B1  a@gmail.com,c@gmail.com,b@gmail.com
```

Answer (score 1):

Let us try

```
df.Email=df.Email.str.split(',').apply(set).str.join(',')
df
  Area    Group         Shift                                Email
0   KM      MFG      A1,A2,A3              a@gmail.com,b@gmail.com
1  RIM     TEST         A1,B1              c@gmail.com,b@gmail.com
2  PNG   FINISH      C1,C2,C3              c@gmail.com,a@gmail.com
3   KL  Manager  NORMAL,B1,B1  c@gmail.com,a@gmail.com,b@gmail.com
```

Comment: You too.. I am rusty...  you have a better answwer. :)